# C - Valgrind detects an error in my reverse-string function

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, reverse, memcheck

I wrote a small program that seems to work fine, but valgrind give me a weird error when I run memcheck. I need help in interpreting the error code :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int get_length(char* str){
   int i=0;
   char c = str[0];
   while(c!='\0'){
   i++;
   c=str[i]; 
   }
   return i;
}

char* rev(char* str){
   int length = get_length(str);
   char* x=malloc(length*sizeof(char));
   int i;
   length-=1;
   for(i=0; i<=length; i++){
      x[i]=str[length-i];
   }
   return x;
}

int main(){
   char* s=rev("roma");
   printf("%s\n",s);
   free(s);
}
```

valgrind output below:

```
Invalid read of size 1
==14727==    at 0x4C29724: __GI_strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:405)
==14727==    by 0x4E9907A: puts (ioputs.c:37)
==14727==    by 0x400673: main (in /home/francesco80b/Scrivania/i_a/l-04/main.o)
==14727==  Address 0x51ba044 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==14727==    at 0x4C28D84: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==14727==    by 0x400601: rev (in /home/francesco80b/Scrivania/i_a/l-04/main.o)
==14727==    by 0x400663: main (in /home/francesco80b/Scrivania/i_a/l-04/main.o)
==14727== 
amor
==14727== 
==14727== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14727==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14727==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 4 bytes allocated
==14727== 
==14727== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

I also noticed that, if I use calloc() instead of using malloc(), valgrind doesn't detects any errors at all.

NOTE: I wrote the get_length() function just for fun, lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You allocated fewer characters than you need:

```
char* x=malloc(length*sizeof(char));
```

should be

```
char* x=malloc(length+1);
```

Multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is unnecessary, because the standard requires it to be `1`. Adding `1` is required, because you need an extra character for the null terminator, which your function fails to add. That is why the invalid read happens when `printf` tries to print the string.

To fix this problem, allocate `length+1`, and add `x[length] = '\0';` before returning `x` from the function.